# How to convert from constrained layout to relative layout

Tags: android, layout

I created an android app with constraint layout as the base layout and I want to convert it into Relative layout. How can I do that without affecting the items inside the layout?

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.intent_basics.MainActivit‌​y">
```

Comment: Show your code it's easier to debug for us than to produce your own code.

Comment: <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.intent_basics.MainActivity">

Comment: Add codes **to your question**, not as comments.

Comment: i tried to add codes it says it should format properly i dont know how to fromat

Comment: Select the text and press `Ctrl`+`+`. Or `Command`+`+`

Comment: @joshua I edit your post accept the modifications

Comment: accepeted  now tell me how to convert it to relative layout

Comment: `How can i do to that without affecting the items inside the layout` There are **no items** in that layout...

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted in your question, your constraint layout does not seem to have any child views. If that's the case, simply replace:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.intent_basics.MainActivit‌​y">

    ...

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

with:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.intent_basics.MainActivit‌​y">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```